# Left and right margin (ident) for a text inside a div in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following code in php inside a div

```
<div class="stage_container_four">
<?php
  if ($answer == $correct && $refer_question == 0) {
            echo $xp_value," ", "Points earned.";
            }
            else {
            echo "Already answered or wrong answer.";
            }
?>
</div>
```

And on CSS I have this:

```
.stage_container_four {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:20px;
    height: 30px;
    float:left !important;
    font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:rgba(160,78,0,1.00);
    line-height: 30px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    text-transform:none !important;
    background-color:rgba(255,202,0,0.70);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I would like the echoed text to be idented 20px both from left and right, however only the left side is idented 20px which is the response expected but the right side text ends where the border for background-color ends. How can I now get a 20px margin or ident from the right side?

Please notice there is no width.

Thanks,
_oliver

Comment: `text-indent` only works on one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.stage_container_four {
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

remove margin and text-indent in css

Comment: @Oliver no problem had plenty of those "right in your face, but refuse to see" moments too